# TryParse from string to float does not give a result

Tags: c#

hey guys i know it's been covered alot i have looked everywhere and tried everything, im making a game where the highscore should be saved as the highest score, to do that i need to make a string into a float as the final time of the level to check if its the highest score but when i do that all i get is 0, i have put two debugs in the code to see what i get and i see the sting as the final time but the float as 0.
i know my code is really bad its the first game im trying to make but im stuck on this for weeks.
i marked my problem with lines please help me!!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Globalization;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{

public string strTag;
public Text timerText;
private float finalTime;
private float startTime;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

    startTime = Time.time;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float t = Time.time - startTime;

    string minutes = ((int)t / 60).ToString();
    string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2");

    timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
  }



  private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
  {
    if (collision.collider.tag == strTag)
    {

 --------------------------------------------------------

        string finalTimeStr = timerText.text;
        float.TryParse(finalTimeStr, NumberStyles.Any, 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out finalTime);    
        Debug.Log(finalTimeStr);
        Debug.Log(finalTime);

 --------------------------------------------------------


        if (finalTime > 0 && finalTime < PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("bestTime" 
  + SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex, 9999))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("bestTime" + 
  SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex, finalTime);
            int Check = 0;
            Check = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Check" + 
  SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex, 0);
            Debug.Log(Check);

            if (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("bestTime" + 
SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex, 9999) < 40 && Check == 0)
            {
                Check++;
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Stars" + 
 SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex, 1);
                Debug.Log(string.Format("{0:N3}", 
PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("bestTime" + 
SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex, 9999)));
            }
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("bestTime" + 
SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex, 9999) < 30 && Check == 1)
            {
                Check++;
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Stars" + 
SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex, 1);
            }
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("bestTime" + 
SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex, 9999) < 25 && Check == 2)
            {
                Check++;
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Stars" + 
SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex, 1);

            }

            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Check" + 
SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex, Check);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: From your code `timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;` is not a float.

Comment: the value of finalTimeStr  is whatever the time it takes you to finish the level, works good the problem is the tryparse.

and yes timerText.text is a string that i put into finalTimeStr as part of trying to make it to work.

Comment: `timerText.text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(t).ToString("m\\:ss")` will display `t` as a string in the format `minutes:seconds` with always 2-digit seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you might consider, if you must use a string to store the time, is to use the `Timespan` class to create and parse the `string` value to and from the `float` value:

```
// This format is for one or two digit minutes and two digit seconds
const string timeFormat = "m\\:ss";

// Get the elapsed seconds
float t = Time.time - startTime;

// Display the seconds as a formatted string
timerText.text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(t).ToString(timeFormat);

// Get the total number of seconds from the formatted time string
float finalTime = (float)TimeSpan.ParseExact(timerText.text, timeFormat, 
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: Well thank you so much for some reason this works while the other didn't, really appreciate it.  if you know do you mind explaining the difference to me?